# Instance variables, .new and missing_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been having some trouble with a form here. Root view is webapp#home, with a form at the bottom to add a new table/table name. The problem is that I've been getting the error below.

> NoMethodError in TablesController#create undefined method `table' for
>
> ```
>               def create
> @table = Table.new(table_params)
> if @table.save
>   redirect_to '/'     else
>       render('new')
> ```

The trace indicates that there is a missing_method for "@table.save". I'm guessing that the form produced a nil value somehow, but I have no idea why that is the case =/. Thanks in advance, and happy 2015!

Controller (Webapp)

```
def home
    @tables = Table.all
    @table = Table.new
  end
```

Code used for the form:

```
<div class="new-table-form"><%= form_for @table do |f| %><p>Table name: <%= f.text_field :table_name %>&nbsp<%= f.submit %><% end %></p></div>
```

Controller (Tables)

```
def create
    @table = Table.new(table_params)
    if @table.save
      redirect_to '/'
    else
        render('new')
    end
```

Comment: Your poor formatting makes this harder than it has to be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the create action you need :

```
@table = Table.create(table_params)
```

not

```
@table = Table.new(table_params)
```

Comment: Turns out that there was a mistake in validating :table_name in the model in addition to the above, but this helped as well. Thanks!